# Issue referencing value in dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue referencing items in a dropdown list. I build a dropdown box based off table header names, and it does successfully populate the drop down. However, I get the error "unable to get the list property of the dropdown class" on the last line below, and I can see during runtime that it's indeed not available. I just don't know how to properly reference an item in this drop down.

```
Dim combo As Object
Set combo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvStats").Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                     Left:=Cells(1, tCols + 2).Left, _
                                     Top:=Cells(1, tCols + 2), _
                                     Width:=200, _
                                     Height:=Cells(1, tCols + 2).Height)

For Each X In tbl.HeaderRowRange 'table that was built earlier in my code
     If InStr(X, "View:") = 0 Then
          With combo
                 .ControlFormat.AddItem X
          End With
     End If
Next

Dim myindex As Long, myitem As String

myindex = combo.ControlFormat.Value
myitem = combo.ControlFormat.List(myindex) 'it gets here and errors out
```

I would like to use this drop down list to change formulas on the spreadsheet later, hopefully there's some sort of on-click event on dropdowns to do this, but I can't even get this part to work right yet.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is this code? If you are creating it presumably it doesn't have a value?

Comment: This code is right after I build the table that holds the column headers I reference to build the drop down. It does appear during run time that the list is empty, which is odd. I can stop execution right before the last line above, and the drop down is indeed populated, so I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Yes your code populates the control with a list, but it won't have a value until someone selects an item from that list. Normally you would extract the value using the change event. Is this a Forms control or ActiveX?

Comment: Ahh, ok. This is a regular form control. In this scenario, can I set the default selection to show the first item so that it has a value?

Comment: `myindex = combo.ControlFormat.Value + 1`

Comment: or `combo.ControlFormat.List(myindex + 1)`

Comment: This seems to work `combo.ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1`.

Comment: `can I set the default selection to show the first item so that it has a value? – Sudio 4 mins ago` For that do what @SJR suggested.

Comment: @SJR's comment did work, so the first option is now selected. Thanks!

Comment: I need to build off this question, but rather than editing the original question I'll post a new one (not sure if this is the right etiquette).

Comment: A new question is probably the better option - better to keep the scope small than large considering the format of the website